# Rosdep failed to install python-catkin-pkg-modules on Debian buster

Tags: ros-melodic, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install ROS Melodic on Raspberrypi4 model B.

My environment:RaspberryPi4 model B 2GB RAM

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.103-v7l+ #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:24:00 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/debian_version 
10.13
```

I followed the steps in this page:[Installing ROS Melodic on the Raspberry Pi](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Melodic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi)

An error occurred when executing the following command

```
rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro melodic -r --os=debian:buster
```

Sorry,Error contains Japanese characters.

Error:

> executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python-catkin-pkg-modules]
> パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
> 依存関係ツリーを作成しています
> 状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
> 以下のパッケージが自動でインストールされましたが、もう必要とされていません:
> python3-rospkg-modules
> これを削除するには 'sudo apt autoremove' を利用してください。
> 以下のパッケージが新たにインストールされます:
> python-catkin-pkg-modules
> アップグレード: 0 個、新規インストール: 1 個、削除: 0 個、保留: 0 個。
> 41.0 kB 中 0 B のアーカイブを取得する必要があります。
> この操作後に追加で 249 kB のディスク容量が消費されます。
> (データベースを読み込んでいます ... 現在 150007 個のファイルとディレクトリがインストールされています。)
> .../python-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.8-1_all.deb を展開する準備をしています ...
> python-catkin-pkg-modules (0.4.8-1) を展開しています...
> dpkg: アーカイブ /var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.8-1_all.deb の処理中にエラーが発生しました (--unpack):
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/topological_order.py' を上書きしようとしています。これはパッケージ python-catkin-pkg 0.4.10-1 にも存在します
> 処理中にエラーが発生しました:
> /var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.8-1_all.deb
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
> executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python-rosdep-modules]
> パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
> 依存関係ツリーを作成しています
> 状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
> E: パッケージ python-rosdep-modules が見つかりません
> executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python3-rosdep-modules]
> パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
> 依存関係ツリーを作成しています
> 状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
> E: パッケージ python3-rosdep-modules が見つかりません
> executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python3-rospkg]
> パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
> 依存関係ツリーを作成しています
> 状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
> 以下のパッケージが自動でインストールされましたが、もう必要とされていません:
> python-catkin-pkg python-rospkg-modules
> これを削除するには 'sudo apt autoremove' を利用してください。
> 以下のパッケージは「削除」されます:
> python-rosdep python-rosdistro python-rosinstall python-rosinstall-generator python-rospkg
> 以下のパッケージが新たにインストールされます:
> python3-rospkg
> アップグレード: 0 個、新規インストール: 1 個、削除: 5 個、保留: 0 個。
> 2,142 B 中 0 B のアーカイブを取得する必要があります。
> この操作後に 776 kB のディスク容量が解放されます。
> (データベースを読み込んでいます ... 現在 150006 個のファイルとディレクトリがインストールされています。)
> python-rosdep (0.14.0-1) を削除しています ...
> python-rosinstall-generator (0.1.14-1) を削除しています ...
> python-rosinstall (0.7.8-2) を削除しています ...
> python-rosdistro (0.7.2-1) を削除しています ...
> python-rospkg (1.1.7-100) を削除しています ...
> 以前に未選択のパッケージ python3-rospkg を選択しています。
> (データベースを読み込んでいます ... 現在 149858 個のファイルとディレクトリがインストールされています。)
> .../python3-rospkg_1.1.7-100_all.deb を展開する準備をしています ...
> python3-rospkg (1.1.7-100) を展開しています...
> python3-rospkg (1.1.7-100) を設定しています ...
> executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python3-catkin-pkg-modules]
> パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
> 依存関係ツリーを作成しています
> 状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
> 以下のパッケージが自動でインストールされましたが、もう必要とされていません:
> python-catkin-pkg python-rospkg-modules
> これを削除するには 'sudo apt autoremove' を利用してください。
> 以下のパッケージが新たにインストールされます:
> python3-catkin-pkg-modules
> アップグレード: 0 個、新規インストール: 1 個、削除: 0 個、保留: 0 個。
> 41.0 kB 中 0 B のアーカイブを取得する必要があります。
> この操作後に追加で 248 kB のディスク容量が消費されます。
> (データベースを読み込んでいます ... 現在 149867 個のファイルとディレクトリがインストールされています。)
> .../python3-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.8-1_all.deb を展開する準備をしています ...
> python3-catkin-pkg-modules (0.4.8-1) を展開しています...
> dpkg: アーカイブ /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.8-1_all.deb の処理中にエラーが発生しました (--unpack):
> '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/topological_order.py' を上書きしようとしています。これはパッケージ python3-catkin-pkg 0.4.10-1 にも存在します
> 処理中にエラーが発生しました:
> /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.8-1_all.deb
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
> ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
> apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python-catkin-pkg-modules] failed
> apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python-rosdep-modules] failed
> apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python3-rosdep-modules] failed
> apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python3-catkin-pkg-modules] failed
> apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [python-catkin-pkg-modules]
> apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [python-rosdep-modules]
> apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [python3-rosdep-modules]
> apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [python3-catkin-pkg-modules]

How can I resolve these errors?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409637/rosdep-failed-to-install-python-catkin-pkg-modules-on-debian-buster/) by [tunamayo](https://answers.ros.org/users/124526/tunamayo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2022-11-21**:
Please edit your question to include more of the error content above. This is mostly the summary and not the full error.

**Comment by [tunamayo](https://answers.ros.org/users/124526/tunamayo/) on 2022-11-22**:
I have added the full error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error you're getting is due to conflicting files installed from different packages. It looks like you have very old versions of some of those packages.

There's a few things I'll flag. First is that you appear to be mixing python2 and python3 which is unexpected for melodic. By default everything should be using python2 in melodic.

Second, I see python3-catkin-pkg-modules is quite old. The instruction that you link to have an `apt-get upgrade` that I think you may have not executed, or your system is old enough you need to use an `apt-get dist-upgrade` to get coverage.

I tried it out on in a clean buster container and wasn't able to reproduce the problem. You may need to understand more about where your image is coming from or what the legacy of that system is. But the primary recommendation is to make sure that your tools are up to date before you try to install the new ones.

And secondly I would strongly recommend that you double check where the different python version is coming from and that that is something that you want to debug and deal with. It will make your experience more complicated.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2022-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tunamayo](https://answers.ros.org/users/124526/tunamayo/) on 2022-11-25**:
I tried an `apt-get` and an `apt-get dist-upgrade` , but nothing updated.

So I reinstalled the OS and it works fine.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2022-11-29**:
Yeah, it sounds like you had some conflicting packages preinstalled on your system.